# For casting local media files, do we need server to upload files

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cast

In my app i implemeted a **chromecast** support for casting local audio files to Android TV. I dig out on google about my query but did't get a any answers which will clear my doubt.

My dobut is for casting any local audio files do i need to create a **http server** and uplaoding audio files to it and then passing URL for casting to cast receiver devices. I don't think this will be the approach.

I heard somewhere that, we have to use any embedded Http library but i dont know how to use it and i have no any idea. it seems bit complicated.

Any sugesstion how can i cast my local audios.

Answer (score 0):

I used xampp to host some video files locally. This way I can just use the url: `http://192.168.x.x/myvideo.mp4` (x.x would be the IP your xampp is running on) to cast my own videos. Audio Files should work the same I guess.

Comment: did you used it in android to cast video on android TV @Ducttapemummy

Comment: No, a Windows PC, but you could use a raspberry pi, a NAS or whatever file hosting service. Your Android device could control what files are hosted, and then give your android TV the URL to display it.